# Angular Material md-select validation issue

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-material

I have several md-select dropdowns on my form, many of which have validation. The validation works correctly on all the dropdowns except for the following, which doesn't prevent the form from submitting if empty:

```
    <md-input-container class="form-input-container"
                        flex="15">
      <label>NDRA*</label>
      <md-select id="registration-information-ndra"
                 name="ndra"
                 ng-model="vm.registration.code"
                 ng-class="{'validation-error': newForm.ndra.$error.required && newForm.$submitted}"
                 ng-required="vm.validation.ndra">
        <md-option ng-repeat="code in vm.dropdowns.codes"
                   value="{{code}}">
          {{code}}
        </md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
```

vm.validation.ndra evaluates to true, so I know that's not the issue. If I look at the values for newForm.ndra vs a working select option, such as newForm.submissionDate, I get the following:

`newForm.ndra: {"$viewValue":"p","$modelValue":"p","$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":true,"$invalid":false,"$error":{},"$name":"ndra","$options":null}`

Registration Type (validation works):

```
 <md-input-container class="form-input-container padded-input md-block"
                            flex-gt-sm="">
          <label>Type of Registration*</label>
          <md-select id="registration-information-type"
                     name="registrationType"
                     ng-model="vm.registration.type"
                     ng-class="{'validation-error': newForm.registrationType.$error.required && newForm.$submitted}"
                     ng-required="vm.validation.registrationType">
            <md-option ng-repeat="type in vm.dropdowns.types"
                       value="{{type}}">
              {{type}}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
```

`{"$validators":{},"$asyncValidators":{},"$parsers":[],"$formatters":[],"$viewChangeListeners":[],"$untouched":true,"$touched":false,"$pristine":true,"$dirty":false,"$valid":false,"$invalid":true,"$error":{"required":true},"$name":"registrationType","$options":null}`

Comment: would you please provide more information on this issue?  do you have a default selection or even an empty selection?

Comment: can you also show the markup for the other option you have listed?

Comment: just added the markup

Comment: have you compared `vm.dropdown.types` to `vm.dropdowns.codes`?  I am guessing that you don't have an empty value option, so no matter what you always have a value and so Angular sees this as having a value

Comment: yeah, they both return arrays of string options for their respective dropdown menus.

Comment: I mean how does the content of the arrays compare?

Comment: type: ["Agency","Court Ordered","In Person","Mail In Third Party","FPCA/FWAB"]
code: ["24","33","49","54","76","82","99","P","FP"]

Comment: You just check the value of `vm.validation.ndra`. It must be false otherwise there in no way `$valid` can be `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Deep in my controller code, the controller was being instantiated, and then `this.registration.code` was being set to `P`, so the model for the ndra dropdown already had a value.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that your `vm.validation.ndra` is returning opposite what your `vm.validation.registrationType` is returning.  so that the select is not required.

if you look at what was returned...

**NDRA**

> ```
> "$valid":true,"$invalid":false
> ```

vs.

**Registration Type**

> ```
> "$valid":false,"$invalid":true
> ```

they are completely opposite.

you should check to make sure that you are getting the right truthy in `vm.validation.ndra`

Comment: That didn't work. I added some more information on the values of the form inputs in my original post.

Comment: I checked both `vm.validation.ndra` and `vm.validation.registrationType` - they both return true.

Comment: take out `vm.validation.ndra` and replace it with `true` in the markup and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value to `false` in `ng-required` and see the result below in the following link. I think `vm.validation.ndra` returns `false`.
http://codepen.io/next1/pen/WwoyWG